# where/what is the output of hotspot's -XX:-CITime flag?

Tags: java, logging, jvm-hotspot, runtime-compilation

I am trying to use the '-XX:-CITime' flag ([documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)) for hotspot JVM, but I have some questions:

1. If I want to *enable* printing compilation time, then do I type '-XX:-CITime' (with a minus) or '-XX:+CITime' (with a plus)?
2. Where does it output the compilation time information?
3. What does is the output supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `-XX:+CITime`. The `-XX:-CITime` in documentation means that this flag is disabled by default. Try using it with `-server -XX:+PrintCompilation` flags
2. the standard output (System.out)
3. sample output:

> ```
> Accumulated compiler times (for compiled methods only)
> ------------------------------------------------
> Total compilation time   :  0.179 s
> Standard compilation   :  0.128 s, Average : 0.004
> On stack replacement   :  0.047 s, Average : 0.024
> ```

Check [this article about JIT diagnostics](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/07/useful-jvm-flags-part-2-flag-categories-and-jit-compiler-diagnostics/).

Comment: Thanks, and nice link. For future googlers, the output only happens when the program exits -- unless someone else knows how to force the output periodically.

Comment: Does this flag still work in JDK 8+? It seems to have no effect for me.